# Animate inside n queue child elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animation

i have the next code working properly. Inside the li i have an element i need to animate opacity so when the li is showed then the text shows, just to avoid the effect of test trying to fill the li when this is in animation, it looks ugly.

Everything i have tried does not work

```
jQuery('.item2').waypoint(function(direction) {
  jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':1},'fast', function(){


    jQuery(this).find('.article-info li').each(function() {
    var li = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(document).queue(function(n) {
      li.animate(
        {width:'show'},
        {queue: true, duration: 150, specialEasing: {width: 'easeOutQuart'},
         complete:n//call the next item in the queue             
      }); 
    });
});
});
```

I have tried this with no luck

```
jQuery('.item2').waypoint(function(direction) {
    jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':1},'fast', function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.article-info li').each(function() {
            var li = jQuery(this);
            jQuery(document).queue(function(n) {
                li.animate(
                    {width:'show'},
                    {queue: true, duration: 150, specialEasing: {width: 'easeOutQuart'}       
                    }).find('.titleofpost').animate({'opacity':1},{queue: true,complete:n//call the next item in the queue             
                    });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to CSS3 and a transition effect

```
li {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: -moz-filter 2s; /* Firefox */
    -o-animation: -o-filter 2s; /* Opera */
}
.animation {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then just remove/add class with jQuery

```
$(this).addClass("animation");
```

It will give you a beautifull animation effect without much JS coding.